# How to delete button after clicking on "delete" button?

Tags: java, swing, button

My program seems to run fine, except for the delete part. Every time I click on the 'delete' button, it deletes itself. So my question is, how would I delete a **selected** button after I clicked on the "delete" button? 
Here is a snippet of my code:

```
public class DeleteButton extends JFrame implements ActionListener 
{    
  JButton b18a = new JButton("Delete");
  JPanel panel = new JPanel();
  panel.add(b18);

  class ClickListenerTwo implements ActionListener
  {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
         JButton buttonThatWasClicked = (JButton) e.getSource();
         Container parent = buttonThatWasClicked.getParent();
         parent.remove(buttonThatWasClicked);
         parent.revalidate();
         parent.repaint();
    }
  }
}
ActionListener b18aClicked = new ClickListenerTwo();
b18a.addActionListener(b18aClicked);
```

**P.S** - This selected button that I'm talking about is made during run time, so I want to delete it during run time too, if that would be possible. Thanks!

Comment: Your code is remove the delete button.  Rather you could modify your code to add some extra button and delete those buttons.  May be your question is you e.getSource() will return only the click Button where as you want to remove some button from Frame.

Comment: Yes, when I create the button during run time, I want to click on the delete button and then click on the button I made so that it deletes.

Comment: I have provided the answer below . I think that  what you are looking for.

Comment: How do you know what's selected?

Comment: @MadProgrammer That's my question...

Comment: @MadProgrammer I have all of my set up to creating the buttons during run time, it's just this part that got me confused.

Comment: What type of button? `JCheckBox`, `JRadioButton`, `JToggleButton`?

Comment: Just a button, JButton

Comment: This program deletes my delete button, and I don't want that.

Comment: So, assuming that you need to click the "other" button first, you could use a instance field to maintain a reference to the "last" clicked button and then use that when the delete button is clicked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, assuming that you need to click the "other" button first, you could use an instance field to maintain a reference to the "last" clicked button and then use that when the delete button is clicked

For example...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JButton lastButton;

        public TestPane() {
            JPanel grid = new JPanel(new GridLayout(8, 8));
            for (int index = 0; index < 8 * 8; index++) {
                JButton btn = new JButton(Integer.toString(index + 1));
                btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        lastButton = btn;
                    }
                });
                grid.add(btn);
            }

            JButton delete = new JButton("Delete");
            delete.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (lastButton != null) {
                        lastButton.getParent().remove(lastButton);
                        grid.revalidate();
                        grid.repaint();
                    }
                    lastButton = null;
                }
            });

            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            add(grid);
            add(delete, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        }

    }

}
```

Personally, a `JToggleButton` would give a better user experience

Comment: Can I make it so I click the delete button first and then the button? Or is that not possible? If so, please tell me. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Kind of, basically though the actual action for removing the button would fall to the individual button. You'd need to set up a flag (set to `true` by the delete button and back to `false` by any other button)

Comment: How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You have to find the Component from the Top Frame. 
May be this code will help you.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    Object source = evt.getSource();
    if (source instanceof Component) {
        Window w = findWindow((Component) source);
        //Find your component and remove it from this window.
    } else {
        System.out.println("source is not a Component");
    }
}

public static Window findWindow(Component c) {
    System.out.println(c.getClass().getName());
    if (c instanceof Window) {
        return (Window) c;
    } else if (c instanceof JPopupMenu) {
        JPopupMenu pop = (JPopupMenu) c;
        return findWindow(pop.getInvoker());
    } else {
        Container parent = c.getParent();
        return parent == null ? null : findWindow(parent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into it.

Comment: Is this all in my ClickListener?

Comment: It says that I can't have static in my inner class? Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: This doesn't delete anything. It just shows my packages.